# Calling a function from an array in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to call the function Greeting from an array. Could someone please give me a hint or direct me to a video or a reading online. Thanks

```
int Greeting()
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}

int process[]={0,0,&Greeting,0,0,0};

int main()
{
    process[2];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have an array of ints.  You need an array of function pointers instead, and then you can store and invoke the function.

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings - it will provide many _hints_ and save you time.

Comment: You don't need `&` before `Greeting`. Function names decay to pointers to functions.

Answer (score 3):

Your `process` is an array of `int`. You need to make it an array of function pointers.

```
int (*process[])(void) = {0, 0, Greeting, 0, 0, 0};
```

Then call the function indirectly

```
process[2]();
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple example in which two function pointers are created first in a structure, then three functions are created. You initialize the function pointers with the function you want to call and then you pass the argument to get the work done.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    /* Any function who take two int parameters and returns int can be pointed by this function pointer. */
    int (*function_name)(int a, int b);

    /* This can point to all functions having int argument and void return type */
    void (*print_fn)(int sum);

} FN_GROUP;

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return (a + b);
}

int subtract(int a, int b)
{
    return (a - b);
}

void show(int num)
{
   printf("Result:%d\r\n", num);
}

int main()
{
    int num1 = 20;
    int num2 = 10;
    int result = 0;   
    FN_GROUP group;

    /* Initialize the pointers with add() and show() functions. */    
    group.function_name = &add;
    group.print_fn = &show;

    /* Now call these functions. */
    result = group.function_name(num1, num2);
    group.print_fn(result);

    /* Initialize the pointers with subtract(). */        
    group.function_name = &subtract;

    /* Now call these functions again */
    result = group.function_name(num1, num2);
    group.print_fn(result);

    return (0);
}
```